# React/JavaScript Refactor Functions to a Separate File Without Losing Scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component with many chained functions for a specific task. Those functions need access to the component's states. I want to separate some of those functions into a new .js file to keep my component file clean, but doing so, the functions lose access to the states.

This is what I have (works fine):

```js
// SomeComponent.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function SomeComponent() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(name)
    func1()
  })

  function func1() {
    console.log(name)
    func2()
  }

  function func2() {
    console.log(name)
    func3()
  }

  function func3() {
    setAccessToken("1234")
  }


  return(
    <h1>{name}</h1>
    <button onClick={func3}>Click Me</button>
  )

}
```

One idea is to send the states and state-setters as parameters all the way down to func3, but there are like 10 chained functions in my actual code and that's too messy.

Another idea is to make a class in the new file and instantiate the class with the states and state-setters as attributes. Maybe a new React Component?

Is there a cleaner way I can define func1, func2, func3 in a separate file while keeping access to the states? Either sending the states and state-setters to the scope of NewFile.js somehow, or bringing the functions to the scope of my component. I just want them in the same scope.

My only problem with the functions is the amount of space that they take in my component file.

I want something like this:

```js
// SomeComponent.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {func1, func2, func3} from './newFile';

export default function SomeComponent() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(name)
    func1()
  })
  
  return(
    <h1>{name}</h1>
    <button onClick={func3}>Click Me</button>
  )
    
}
```

```js
// NewFile.js
function func1() {
  console.log(name)
  func2()
}
  
function func2() {
  console.log(name)
  func3()
}

function func3() {
  setAccessToken("1234")
}

export {func1, func2, func3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this sort of situation I sometimes like to use a custom hook to separate functions from the rendered JSX. Here, you could do:

```
export const useSomeComponent = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(name)
        func1()
    })

    function func1() {
        console.log(name)
        func2()
    }

    function func2() {
        console.log(name)
        func3()
    }

    function func3() {
        setAccessToken("1234")
    }
    return { name, func3 }; // return only the values used externally
};
```

```
import { useSomeComponent } from './useSomeComponent';
export default function SomeComponent() {
    const { name, func3 } = useSomeComponent();
    // note that if you're returning more than one element, a fragment must surround it
    return (<>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <button onClick={func3}>Click Me</button>
    </>);
}
```

It makes a big difference when both the function definitions/hooks and the JSX is long, by focusing on only one thing at a time in a file - the layout/markup, or the logic.